# Nested for loops python - duplicated values

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl

im trying to build a GUI on Tkinter that allow user to input values in entries (10 rows and 2 columns. The entries were created using a for loop. So far so good.
Next i need is that this data goes to a excel sheet the same way its being written in the Tkinter GUI (10 rows and 2 columns)
I can't figure out a way to do this, im stuck right now because the data in the first and second column is being written at first, but then the for loop continues and keeps pasting the same value on column one. I tried using zip function but so far i can't make it work.
Can someone guide me on this one?

```
from tkinter import *
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1366x768")
height_value=root.winfo_screenheight()
width_value=root.winfo_screenwidth()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value, height_value))


book = Workbook()
hoja = book.active

my_entries = list()
my_entries1 = list()


def guardar_datos():
    columnas = 1
    fila = 2
    valor = "21-0"

    for entries1 in (my_entries):
        for entries2 in (my_entries1):
            hoja.cell(row=fila, column= columnas, value=valor+entries1.get()).font = Font(name='Arial', size=13)
            if entries2.get() == "":
                hoja.delete_rows(fila)
            columnas +=1
            hoja.cell(row=fila, column= columnas, value=entries2.get()).font = Font(name='Arial', size=13)
            columnas -=1
        
        
            if len(entries1.get()) <= 4 or entries1.get().isalpha() == True:
                hoja.delete_rows(fila)
                fila -=1
            fila += 1
    book.save('C:\\Programa_pases\\lista_CUIJ.xlsx')
    

for y in range (10):
    #for x in range(2):
        my_label = Label(root,text="CUIJ",font = "Arial 24 bold")
        my_label.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="N")
        my_label1 = Label(root,text="Observación",font = "Arial 24 bold")
        my_label1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="N")
        my_label2 = Label(root, width=5,text="21-0",font = "Arial 12").grid(padx=5, pady=5,sticky = 'w', row=y+1, column=0)
        my_label3 = Label(root, width=5,text="Observ",font = "Arial 12").grid(padx=5, pady=5,sticky = 'w', row=y+1, column=1)
        
        my_entry = Entry(root,width=40,font = "Arial 12 bold")
        my_entry.grid(row=y+1,column=0,padx=65,pady=15,sticky = "e",ipadx=20,ipady=2)
        my_entry.focus() 
        my_entries.append(my_entry)
    
        my_entry1 = Entry(root,width=40,font = "Arial 12 bold")
        my_entry1.grid(row=y+1,column=1,padx=65,pady=15,sticky = "e",ipadx=20,ipady=2)
        my_entries1.append(my_entry1)

my_button1 = Button(root, text="Guardar",command=guardar_datos,font = "Arial 13 bold")
my_button1.grid(row=20,column=0, sticky = '')
        

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first goes over my_entries and for every entry you run 10 inserts into your table.

As my_entries and my_entries are equal in size, you can run this.

Maybe you should add some checks for validity of the entry

```
def guardar_datos():
    columnas = 1
    fila = 2
    valor = "21-0"
    for x in range(0, len(my_entries)):
        if not my_entries[x].get().isspace() and not my_entries1[x].get().isspace():
            hoja.cell(row=fila, column= columnas, value=valor+my_entries[x].get()).font = Font(name='Arial', size=13)
            hoja.cell(row=fila, column= columnas+1 , value=my_entries1[x].get()).font = Font(name='Arial', size=13)
            fila += 1
    book.save('D:\\lista_CUIJ.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you have been very helpful!